# PageSpeed Insights - Total Blocking Time

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, pagespeed

Hey so I'm seeing wild inconsistencies with PageSpeed insights.
I know quite a bit about the specific on each core web vital.
However, maybe I'm missing something.

9/10 I'm getting 95+ ... but sometimes my score will just TANK due to TBT (and sometimes LCP).

Here's my past scores ran 14 times. (this is mobile)

99, 99, 99, 100, 97, 99, 81(650ms)!!!!!!!!!, 99, 99, 98, 100, 98, 99, 94(240ms tbt)!!, 100

I'm using react.

Whenever this happens there's a greyed suggestion (Avoid long main-thread tasks):
(Replaced site name with `example` for privacy)

```
…js/main.39443e3e.js(example.com)
1,530 ms
322 ms
…js/main.39443e3e.js(example.com)
1,852 ms
288 ms
https://example.com
1,028 ms
207 ms
…js/main.39443e3e.js(example.com)
// 2,140 ms
204 ms
https://example.com
780 ms
72 ms
…js/main.39443e3e.js(example.com)
2,344 ms
53 ms
https://example.com
977 ms
51 ms
https://example.com
```

Does anyone have any ideas what's going on here? Is it just PageSpeed Insights being flaky? I need to send a link so clients can see the score for themselves... but I don't like 1/10 sending a bad score for seemingly no reason.

Answer (score 0):

For performance testing, whatever is going on in the machine and network can add noise to your measurement.

- If you opened up a new program while that 650ms run was happening, will cause a spike.
- If the server had a bunch of requests come in at one time, spike!

For performance testing, I have a few suites that I use. I have one that is on AWS, isolated on the network with nothing else running on the box. If I use a shared VM, I get spikes. It has to be a dedicated VM with an excessive amount of ram, and all 10 runs will be within 5% of each other.